# How to properly use <xsl:for-each> with <xsl:result-document> to output multiple XML files?

Tags: xml, xslt, automation, xslt-2.0

I'm looking to transform one XML file into multiple based on a certain node, and how many of them there are in the XML file. The XML im looking to manipulate looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PurchaseOrder xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <StoreFrontName>Store front name</StoreFrontName>
    <PurchaseOrderNumber>7291</PurchaseOrderNumber>
    <PurchaseOrderDate>2019-07-09</PurchaseOrderDate>
    <OrdByAddress>
        <Name>First Name Last Nam</Name>
    </OrdByAddress>
    <PurchaseOrderItemDetail id="1">
        <LineNumber>2224</LineNumber>
        <VendorProductID/>
        <VendorProductDescription>Vend Product Desc</VendorProductDescription>
        <CustomerProductID/>
        <CustomerProductDescription>Cust Prod Desc</CustomerProductDescription>
        <OrderQuantity>1</OrderQuantity>
    </PurchaseOrderItemDetail>
    <PurchaseOrderItemDetail id="2">
        <LineNumber>2219</LineNumber>
        <VendorProductID/>
        <VendorProductDescription>Vend Product Desc</VendorProductDescription>
        <CustomerProductID/>
        <CustomerProductDescription>Cust Prod Desc</CustomerProductDescription>
        <OrderQuantity>1</OrderQuantity>
    </PurchaseOrderItemDetail>
    <PurchaseOrderItemDetail id="3">
        <LineNumber>2220</LineNumber>
        <VendorProductID/>
        <VendorProductDescription>Vend Product Desc</VendorProductDescription>
        <CustomerProductID/>
        <CustomerProductDescription>Cust Prod Desc</CustomerProductDescription>
        <OrderQuantity>1</OrderQuantity>
    </PurchaseOrderItemDetail>
    <PurchaseOrderItemDetail id="4">
        <LineNumber>2221</LineNumber>
        <VendorProductID/>
        <VendorProductDescription>Vend Product Desc</VendorProductDescription>
        <CustomerProductID/>
        <CustomerProductDescription>Cust Prod Desc</CustomerProductDescription>
        <OrderQuantity>1</OrderQuantity>
    </PurchaseOrderItemDetail>
    <PurchaseOrderItemDetail id="5">
        <LineNumber>2222</LineNumber>
        <VendorProductID/>
        <VendorProductDescription>Vend Product Desc</VendorProductDescription>
        <CustomerProductID/>
        <CustomerProductDescription>Cust Prod Desc</CustomerProductDescription>
        <OrderQuantity>1</OrderQuantity>
    </PurchaseOrderItemDetail>
    <PurchaseOrderItemDetail id="6">
        <LineNumber>2223</LineNumber>
        <VendorProductID/>
        <VendorProductDescription>Vend Product Desc</VendorProductDescription>
        <CustomerProductID/>
        <CustomerProductDescription>Cust Prod Desc</CustomerProductDescription>
        <OrderQuantity>1</OrderQuantity>
    </PurchaseOrderItemDetail>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

My XSLT is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"
        name="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="PurchaseOrder">
        <xsl:for-each select="PurchaseOrder/PurchaseOrderItemDetail">
            <xsl:result-document format="xml" href="PurchaseOrderItemDetail{position()}.xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes">
                <PurchaseOrderItemDetail>
                    <StorefrontName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="PurchaseOrder/StorefrontName"/>
                    </StorefrontName>
                    <OrderdBy>
                        <xsl:value-of select="OrdByAddress/Name"/>
                    </OrderdBy>
                    <PurchaseOrderNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select="PurchaseOrder/OrderId"/>
                    </PurchaseOrderNumber>
                    <LineNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select="PurchaseOrder/PurchaseOrderItemDetail/LineNumber"/>
                    </LineNumber>
                    <PurchaseOrderDate>
                        <xsl:value-of select="PurchaseOrder/OrderDateUtc"/>
                    </PurchaseOrderDate>
                    <OrderQuantity>
                        <xsl:value-of select="PurchaseOrder/PurchaseOrderItemDetail/OrderQuantity"/>
                    </OrderQuantity>
                </PurchaseOrderItemDetail>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All I get when I try and transform the XML (using XMLspear) is the tag for encoding, followed an error stating that theres "Open unformatted source pane with given content" and and LSException: Premature end of file.

I've also tried "copy-of" instead of "value-of" for the actual transform of the nodes I want but it had no affect on my issue.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Most XPath expressions inside the `for-each` seem to be wrong, each `PurchaseOrderItemDetail` is the context node inside of the `for-each`, so to create shallow copy cotaining selected child elements use e.g. `<xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="LineNumber, OrderQuantity"/></xsl:copy>`, to copy elements referencing children from the parent or ancestor use the path reaching up e.g. `<xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::PurchaseOrder/StorefrontName, LineNumber, OrderQuantity"/></xsl:copy>`. Of course you can also create new elements but make sure you use the right path to select the values.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Based on your tips, my for-each section is now set up as follows, but I still only get the encoding to output. My apologies, I am new to XSLT and haven't found very much clear and concise documentation on it

Comment: <code>
<xsl:template match="PurchaseOrder">
  <xsl:for-each select="/PurchaseOrderItemDetail">
   <xsl:result-document format="xml" href="PurchaseOrderItemDetail{position()}.xml"
    encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::PurchaseOrder/StorefrontName, LineNumber, OrderDateUtc, OrderQuantity"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</code>

Comment: If you match on `PurchaseOrder`, that element is the context node for the instructions inside and you need to use relative path expressions like `xsl:for-each select="PurchaseOrderItemDetail"`. As for not finding documentation, not sure where you look but any XSLT and XPath tutorial should get you on the right path for that task. Even the info section on the [tag:xslt] here should lead you to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info and it has a link to a book "Practical Transformation Using XSLT and XPath" for instance https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

For `LineNumber` and `OrderQuantity` you can just do `<xsl:copy-of select="LineNumber"/>`, etc.

For `StoreFrontName` and `PurchaseOrderNumber` you can do `<xsl:copy-of select="/*/PurchaseOrderNumber"/>`, etc.

In most cases your mistake is that the context is wrong: you need to think about which element is the context node, and make sure your paths start from there.

In other cases you've just been careless about naming, e.g. the capitalisation of `StoreFrontName` is wrong, and there is no element called `OrderId`.

Comment: I appreciate you catching a lot of those errors on my end as far as the nodes go. Would you suggest using copy-of instead of value-of in all situatuions?

Comment: No, of course not. `xsl-copy-of` copies the entire node, including tags and internal structure, while `xsl:value-of` extracts the string value. Both are needed in different situations.